# Adjusting header and footer and graphics, landscape,

Tags: tables, graphics, header-footer

```
\begin{landscape}
   \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth, angle=0]{epsFig.eps}
    \caption{Insert caption}
    \end{figure}

\begin{tabular}{ l | c || r }
  \hline                        
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
  \hline  
\end{tabular}
   \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth, angle=0]{epsFig.eps}
    \caption{Insert caption}
    \end{figure}
    \end{landscape}
```

I have following problems.

1. Using landscape don't adjust figures on the page. Header side and footer is not the same. So I get image on landscape close to left and there is much bigger space on right side of the page. (landscape)
2. Page one I get Fig. 1, page 2 Fig. 2 but table at the end. I want to have it on specified page, say page 2. I used `\newpage` also but it didn't help.

Comment: Please always post _complete_ documents showing all packages used, and using a \rule rathar than a figure so it can be run locally. `\centering` should work in landscape but it is impossible to see why not since you hav enot posted the relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to answer your first part with the information given but to answer your second question, if you want to force a page break and prevent floats floating past that point then you need to use `\clearpage` not `\newpage`. Or (depending on your needs) close the landscape environment and re-open it later (as landscape issuse `\clearpage` while it is changing the orientation).